# How to keep Notification click event after refresh the page in web?

Tags: javascript, web

```
function sendNotification (title = 'Hi') {
  var a = new Notification(title, {
    requireInteraction: true,
    renotify: true,
    tag: 123,
  })

  a.onclick = function () { // Click event will lose after refresh
    console.log('get')  
  }
}

if (!("Notification" in window)) {
  alert("not support");
}

else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
  // If it's okay let's create a notification
  sendNotification()
}

else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
  Notification.requestPermission()
  .then(
    permission => {
      if (permission === "granted") {
        sendNotification()
      }
    }
  )
}
```

The above code will create a notification and keep the notification does not disappear.When I click on the notification will log 123, but after refresh the page I lost the notification of click event and the variable a.

For the convenience of testing, I added the authentication.You can copy the code to the browser console debug.

Comment: Did you try to trigger the `a.onclick` on the `onload event` ?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue , did you get anywhere with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
document.onload = function(){
    a.onclick = function () {
      console.log(123)
    }
};
```